# How to random cloud texture brush?

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I'd like to have a random cloud pattern. As you can see, the "clouds" now have a linear direction. I could simulate randomness by stroking in circles (not the render type), but it still looks directional.

It was made with cloud texture applied to a sculpting brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is change **Mapping** to **Random** and also you can add **Random** for **Rotation**. In **Brush** settings.

[image]